# C++ Auto Comment Block Tools

Tags: c++, comments, autocommenting

Are there any tools (command line or otherwise) that will allow me to define a function comment header of my choosing (not an XML comment) and mass insert into a number of files?

I have some old code that I'm porting that contains virtually no comments whatsoever and I'd like to split the functions up with headings so I can see where they seperate a bit easier. I do have the collapsing icon within VS2010 but that just isn't enough for me.

I almost feel like I need to grab a copy of Lex and Yacc and write some sort of beautifier myself but just don't have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I think I just answered my own question - UniversalIndentGUI (free) has an "insert comment text from file before function declaration" option! Awesome!